# How to capture the Key combinations in the installation wizard user interface

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-installer, setup-project

I have to configure the Shortcut Key combination in the installation wizard user interface.

If the user, keeps the focus on a particular user interface textbox and presses different key combinations (Eg: CTRL+F3) together then the same must be displayed in the user interface text box.

How to do this in the installation Setup Wizard User Interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not supported by Windows Installer, so it can be done only with a custom external UI. I don't know any setup authoring tools which have this type of control, so you may have to implement one yourself.

An easier approach would be to retrieve this information from within your application.